# Google Analytics HTTP vs HTTPS

Tags: google, google-analytics, https

I want to use Google Analytics on a website that uses both HTTP and HTTPS that works as explained below:

1. Secure pages accessed through `https://mydomain.com/secure/*` are always on HTTPS. Any access to these pages through HTTP will be redirected to HTTPS.
2. Any other pages will be accessible through both HTTP and HTTPS

I have a Google Analytics profile with URL using HTTPS. Will I cover all traffic? Do I need to create another profile using HTTP and how should I apply the other profile?

Answer (score 2):

The same tracking code will capture all traffic to your site, no need for separate profiles or duplicate codes. Follow best practices for SEO though and use canonical tags for the pages accessible in both http/https and 301 redirects for the non SSL pages redirecting to SSL versions.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the same Google Analytics tracking code on both your HTTP and HTTPS pages so that you can view a summary of all your traffic.  If you use separate tracking codes, you will only have access to separate reports and not be able to easily see aggregate statistics.

Comment: Thanks for your response Stephen Ostermiller. So it doesn't matter I use either http or https for default URL in my property setting? Thanks.